# How to deploy with automatic migration enabled?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I don't understand the concept of automatic migration.

Having set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` in the `Migrations.Configuration` class I can't find the place where migration steps are stored.

How will Entity Framework recognize the current state of a production database and update it accordingly when, e.g., my console application is run at the customers' office?

Any information on this is very appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly caution against using Automatic migrations at all, much less at a client site.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first question: They aren't stored anywhere. Automatic migrations only means that the migration will take place without you having to do anything about it. Generating a migration file only occurs when you are doing a manual migration. The only trace that automatic migration leaves is a new record in the `_MigrationHistory` table of your database--which will only be a serialized version of the new model, and not what your changes were.

To answer your second question: You shouldn't have to. Once you're in production, your client shouldn't be able to adjust the database themselves. That's just a terrible idea.

Comment: I believe it's a good idea to have customers update their application whenever they want to. The application should automatically recognize the database's current state and migrate it accordingly for the new version. I've seen this before and it was very comfortable. [Idempotent Migration scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#idempotent) perform exactly this purpose. But I don't know how this is done using automatic migration.