# Mixing automatic and explicit migrations on the production environment

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131955/how-to-deploy-with-automatic-migration-enabled), and I'm wondering how automatic migrations mixed with explicit migrations would be applied on the production environment.

Let us say I create migrations in the following order:

- Explicit Migration A
- Explicit Migration B
- Automatic Migration C
- Explicit Migration D

Since no file is created for the automatic migration, how can we be sure that the automatic migration SQL that will be created on the production environment will be the same as the one created on our development machine ?

I have a sense that as soon as we have a first release on production, we should purely stop using automatic migration...

Comment: Just to be sure, by migration you mean a class that inherits from `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration` and overrides Up and Down methods?

Comment: @JozefLačný Yes absolutely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented with such scenarios before and given your migrations order this is how EF is going to behave:

1. When you have all those applied to database and you execute `Update-Database -TargetMigration:0`, then all of them will be reverted in the same order as applied.
2. When after execute `Update-Database`, all explicit migrations will be applied to the database, and given you have set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` the `[Timestamp]_[YourLastMigrationName]_AutomaticMigration` be applied.

Beware of the fact, that EF handles the order of execution of automatic migrations! I thought that issues would occur, when I created a new table `XY` in the automatic migration and the following `Explicit Migration D` could rely on that table to be in database (and many other scenarios). But since the migrations have the snapshots of database in them, EF will be able to recover from this situation and somehow rearrange the automatic migrations.

To conclude: Without digging into entity-framework's code, I don't recommend such approach - wouldn't try my luck. In my projects I only use **explicit migrations**, that are maintained in **one specific - usually master or iteration branch only** (because of the issues when one team member has created migration B on top of A and another has created C on top of A).

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it really answered my question, because since you mention "Update-Database" I assume you are talking of the case when you do it on development machine.

I think the things are different on the product environment because all migrations are applied in one go. On the development machine, it's easier for EF because you have to call Update-Database before creating an other migration.Therefore, EF can check the model snapshot etc. On the production environment, you move from model A to model D in one go, so I wonder how it can creates the correct Automatic migration without

Comment: Without the snapshot C

Comment: The snapshot of C is really stored in the resx file of D. In production, when you `update-database` from scratch, given the case we discuss, EF will be able to recover (according to my experiments). The order of migrations might change (because if somehow calculates diffs and necessary changes from resx) but it will work. As I said, I personally wouldn't count on it, in our team we strictly do explicit migrations.

Comment: Thanks! Yea I think the same about sticking to explicit migration, but they have been mixed by mistake so I was looking for a way to deal with it.Thanks a lot